# I can't get data from gitlab Graphql

Tags: gitlab, graphql, gitlab-api

I'm trying to make a graphql query but I can't retrieve the MergeRequests from a open repository. What am i doing wrong?

```
{
  project(fullPath: "gitlab-org/gitlab-ce") {
    archived
    forksCount
    mergeRequests(last: 2) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query returned empty edges...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in this last gitlab version :)